# Overriding background color of Theme.Holo.Light

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I noticed that the background color is `@android:color/background_holo_light`, which is a very light grey. I want to override this. I want the background color to be completely white. 100% pure no bullshit white.... and I can't seem to get it.

I've tried making my own style with background as `#FFFFFF`, I've tried changing the layouts background color, nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for

```
<style name="White.Theme" parent="@style/myAppTheme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/WHITE</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That worked for me when I had my parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"

Comment: What was @color/WHITE for you?

Comment: Did you apply the theme in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yeah. It is very perplexing, because even other elements don't turn into pure white... Not sure what to make of this. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the contens of my theme XML, it was too long to post in a comment of my previous answer. Where @style/myAppTheme inherited Holo.Light using the parent tag

```
<resources>
<color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
<color name="green">#ff00ff00</color>

<color name="color_lightgreen">#ffd7ffb2</color>
<color name="color_lightyellow">#ffffffc1</color>
<color name="color_lightgrey">#e6e6e6e6</color>


<!-- EARTH TONES -->
<color name="color_earth_white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="color_earth_yellow">#EFC84A</color>
<color name="color_earth_orange">#E27C3E</color>
<color name="color_earth_black">#000000</color>
<color name="color_earth_teal">#334D5C</color>
<color name="color_earth_dark">#102A39</color>
<color name="color_earth_light">#6A808C</color>
<color name="color_earth_purple">#333574</color>
<color name="color_earth_rose">#7C4554</color>
<color name="color_earth_green">#597943</color>



<!-- PARTY TIME -->
<color name="color_party_green">#C6F269</color>
<color name="color_party_green_light">#ECF7D6</color>
<color name="color_party_orange">#FFB16E</color>
<color name="color_party_orange_light">#ffcda2</color>
<color name="color_party_dark">#7461C1</color>
<color name="color_party_dark_light">#c2bdd6</color>
<color name="color_party_complement">#D65DA4</color>
<color name="color_party_complement_light">#e4c6d8</color>


<color name="color_bg_sent">@color/color_party_orange</color>
<color name="color_bg_recv">@color/color_party_orange_light</color>

<color name="color_error">@color/color_earth_yellow</color>
<!-- /////////////////// END OF COLORS //////////////////////////////// -->



<style name="Theme.Plum" parent="@style/myAppTheme">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_earth_teal</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonLight.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextLight.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewLight.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewLight.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBar.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/ContextMenuItem.Plum</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.Plum</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_earth_teal</item>    <!-- Title Text -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/color_earth_orange</item>   <!-- Set Value -->
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/color_earth_yellow</item>  <!-- Group Text -->
</style>


<style name="ContextMenuItem.Plum" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Plum" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_earth_yellow</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextLight.Plum" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/color_earth_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewLight.Plum" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_white</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewLight.Plum.Invert" parent="@style/TextViewLight.Plum">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_teal</item>
</style>


<style name="AlertDialog.Plum" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_orange</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>


<style name="ProgressBar.Plum" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/plumyellow_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/plumyellow_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewLight.Plum" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_earth_dark</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/color_earth_white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/color_earth_light</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">false</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonLight.Plum" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_earth_orange</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_earth_white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>


</resources>
```